# what is the use of "remote tracking branch" in egit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am new to git and egit. First thing i did was i clone one git repo. Now when I switch to git repositoy view in eclipse, I can see Local and Remote Traking folder under branch. I am not sure what is the purpose of Remote tracking here ?

Comment: See e. g. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: i am not sure i understood clearly.

Comment: Under _Local_ all local and under _Remote Traking_ all remote branches are listed. You work with a local branch and in a remote branch, you can see the history to the last fetch from the remote repository. A typical use case is to check out a remote branch as a new local branch. The upstream branch of the newly created local branch is then the remote branch from where you created the branch.

Comment: one follow up question. Does my remote tracking branch automatically update with changes made on remote repo by other user.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *remote tracking branch* in EGit is the same as in the command line Git:

Under *Local* all local and under *Remote Traking* all [remote branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) are listed. You can only **work on a local branch** and in a **remote branch**, you can see the **history** (until the last fetch) from the remote repository.

A typical use case is to check out a remote branch as a new local branch. The **upstream branch** of the newly created local branch is then the remote branch from where you created the branch.

- The [**fetch**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories) command is to update your remote tracking branches only.
- The [**pull**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch) command gets, in addition, the fetched changed into your current checked-out local branch.